# I can't seem to import the adecuate modules in my .ts proyect

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, node-modules

I've been trying to complite a github proyect and as there where no clear instructions, I went whit the code and what I saw. I went pretty far but go stuck in my current problem, I can't seem to import some modules that the program requires me to have.
The git is:"https://github.com/ottomated/turtle-gambit"
In the index file for example i can't seem to import ws, carlo or path, Even though I've tryed using npm install 'previous names'. I would be very gratefull if anyone could help me figure this out. The rest of the info about this code I've got came from this video of the creator making it:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwKRbsDbxqc&t"